# change / rename column if exists mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, alter-table, mariadb-10.3

I couldn't remane my column if it existed, this is what i tried (i'm adding the different lines tested in same ALTER my_table to summarize) :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  RENAME IF EXISTS column_name TO column_name_new column_definition;
  RENAME IF EXISTS column_name column_name_new column_definition;
  RENAME COLUMN column_name TO column_name_new column_definition;
  RENAME COLUMN column_name column_name_new column_definition;
```

everything returned me this error :
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN column_name TO column_name_new Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN column_name TO column_name_new' at line 2   0.000 sec

Note : column_definition correspond to the name /data type, with the optional constraint, default value, security.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name varchar(10);
```

You must include the type of the new column even if it has not changed.

To rename the table itself, but not the COLUMN, use
RENAME TABLE old_name TO new_name;

Tested in mariadb v. 15.1

Comment: indeed, i forgot to add it in the post but if you don't you will have a syntax error. i'll edit that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/ using this as the reference, I found that RENAME (COLUMN) IF EXISTS well doesn't exist.

This is the solution present in the documentation :

```
 CHANGE [COLUMN] [IF EXISTS] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition [FIRST|AFTER col_name]
```

Example that worked :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  CHANGE COLUMN IF EXISTS column_name column_name_new TYPE DEFAULT VALUE;
```

This code can be reexecuted without error, tested with mariaDB 10.3.